# How to run a cmd command through Runtime.getRuntime.exec() with administrator privileges in java?

Tags: java

How to run a cmd command through Runtime.getRuntime.exec() with administrator privileges for example "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" and also I need the output of executed command!

Comment: Seems off topic, show what you have tried and where you are stuck, also do read our [what topics are allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState\"");
```

for detail refer

https://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt